# Protractor disable SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER in one suite

Tags: selenium, asynchronous, selenium-webdriver, async-await, protractor

Due to [disabling Selenium's control flow](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md#disabling-the-control-flow) in the future, I'm trying to write new specs using `async/await`.

To do this, I have to use `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false` config option, which is unfortunately making my old specs that use Promise Manager fail.

I've tried setting this option in `beforeAll`hook, but then I get the following error:

`TypeError: Unable to create a managed promise instance: the promise manager has been disabled by the SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER environment variable: undefined`

If it's possible, I'd like to avoid having separate protractor conf files for async/non-async specs - it would make my grunt exec command even more complicated that it is now.

Is there any other option to set this flag only for one or few specs/suites?

Answer (score 0):

**Analysis:**

The 'SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false' in protractor config file should be global level,  find a way to disable on spec level.

**Possbile Solution:**

add 'promise.USE_PROMISE_MANAGER = false' before spec use await, and revert to true at the end of spec. I'm not try as that, if it workable, please tell me.

[image]